# Best coefficient between two data sets

Tags: statistics, correlation, multinomial-coefficients

I want to determinate a sensor coefficient but I struggle with a basic math problem...

Here are my values :

```
Newton      Bytes
-----------------
0           2300
0.0196133   2333
0.04903325  2374
0.0980665   2415
0.196133    2524
0.4903325   2848
0.980665    3380
1.96133     4343
2.941995    4610
```

What I need is to find the newton value from any bytes I get. For example if I measure 4600 bytes I need to recover ~2.9N

---

First I calculated coefficients for each row (Newton/Byte) and I've made an average of all these coefficients but it doesn't work at all. It was 0.0002124330614 (without the first row) but 4610 * 0.0002124330614 = 0.979316413 which is far less than 2.94

Secondly I calculated the correlation coefficient which is 0.983871813 but this number doesn't help me. Except that now I know that the curve is almost linear.

---

How to get a global coefficient that correlate the datasets like:

```
2300 * coeff = 0
2500 * coeff ≈ 0.19
4500 * coeff ≈ 2.8
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have in mind any theoretical model for $Bytes$ vs. $Newton$ ?.

Comment: Also stats.stackexchange.com would be a good place to post as well

Comment: I think it's more a math problem than a stat/machine learning/etc...

@FelixMarin no I don't have a model in mind. Or I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the least squares regression line were of the form
$$\text{Newtons} = \text{coeff} \cdot \text{bytes}$$
then that line would go through the origin. If you plot this data, it is nearly linear, *but it does not go through the origin*.

[image]

Using your favorite statistical package (or Excel or Google Sheets) you can find that the least squares line for predicting Newtons from bytes is
$$\text{Newtons} \approx 0.001143 \cdot \text{bytes} -2.696.$$

Plugging in $2300$, $2500$, and $4500$ gives $-0.0671$, $0.1615$, and $2.4475$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you it helped me. I completely forgot about this y=ax+b formula....
I knew I was close with the trendline I already drawed in my chart but I didn't thought about showing the formula

Comment: This looks like a straight line except that one point is not on the line.  Might that not be a better way to describe it than the equation you've given?  Maybe one should look into whether that's explained by something different about that one point. $\qquad$

Comment: On closer inspection, (1) there's a bit of curvature at the lower end, and (2) the points get further apart as the values increase, and (3) a pattern in the Newton's column is obscure by the odd units.  If all of them are divided by the first positive number in that column, then the column becomes this: $$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}  0  & 1  & 2.5 & 5 & 10 & 25 &  50 & 100 & 150 \end{array}$$

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure a linear equation is the best way to describe this data, but it seems that was what OP wanted to do.